# I get Error: Type 'Dio' not found when using Retrofit and Dio together

Tags: flutter, retrofit, dio

I just added `retrofit` to my Flutter app and generated a class as explained [here](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit/versions/3.0.1).

But when I want to run my app I get the following error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleAppdevDebug'...                    
lib/folder/service.g.dart:14:9: Error: Type 'Dio' not found.
```

I use the following dependencies

```
dependencies:
  dio: ^4.0.6
  retrofit: 3.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  json_serializable: ^6.2.0
  analyzer: ^2.8.0
  build_verify: ^3.0.0
  retrofit_generator: 3.0.1
  build_runner: ^2.1.2
```

The class definition looks like this

```dart
@RestApi(baseUrl: 'https://someapi.com/')
abstract classService {
  factory Service(dio.Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _Service;

  @Headers({
    'contentType': 'application/json',
  })
  @POST('path')
  Future<User> createUser(
    @Body() User user,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. When I defined the abstract class and added the @Headers annotation the IDE complained that both DIO and Retrofit contained a `headers` annotation and that I therefore should specify an alias import:

[image]

Which I then did by specifying `import 'package:dio/dio.dart' as dio;`

The alias import though was the reason why the generated `_Service` file couldn't find `Dio`.

Solution:

- Import retrofit as `import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart' as rf;`
- Define the headers as `rf.Headers()`

```dart
@rf.Headers({
    'contentType': 'application/json',
})
@POST('path')
Future<User> createUser(
  @Body() User user,
);
```

Comment: U could also import 'package:dio/dio.dart' hide Headers;